# Prolog: Code Explanation about list and recursive wanted

Tags: prolog

the following code works, but if need help to understand how it is working.

```
%Multiplication of List Elements, Lists have same length

listmulti([],[],[]).
listmulti([H1|B1],[H2|B2],[Result|Spare]) :-
   listmulti(B1,B2,Spare),
   Result is H1 * H2.
```

Everything is understandable, but not the Spare variables. Without it the code don't work.

I added my Prolog trace here, to see what happens.

```
trace,(listmulti([2,1],[3,5],Result)).
 Call:listmulti([2, 1], [3, 5], _5956)
 Call:listmulti([1], [5], _6268)
 Call:listmulti([], [], _6274)
 Exit:listmulti([], [], [])
 Call:_6272 is 1*5
 Exit:5 is 1*5
 Exit:listmulti([1], [5], [5])
 Call:_6266 is 2*3
 Exit:6 is 2*3
 Exit:listmulti([2, 1], [3, 5], [6, 5])
Result = [6, 5]
```

What are the _5956 and so on digits? Help variables from Prolog?
What happens with the Spare variable, it is Empty all the time? Why i need the Spare variable? Why I can't write only [Result] so like this

```
listmulti([H1|B1],[H2|B2],[Result])
```

Thanks for your answers in advance and best greetings.

Comment: These are variables.

Comment: @lurker So i need [Result | Spare] cause this list has undefined much possible list elements?
That Result is not the same as [Result], I know. But I cant not write easily:
```
listmulti([H1|B1],[H2|B2],Result).
```
or?

Comment: Yes, you could use a head/tail form for the result argument if it's useful for you to have a result in terms of a head and a tail. Not sure what you mean when you say you can't write `listmulti([H1|B1],[H2|B2],Result)` easily. Why would it be easier to write `listmulti([H1|B1],[H2|B2],[Result | Spaere])`? Are you referring to the query, or your predicate?

Comment: @lurker
I need here a Head and Tail as result, I think not. Not for having a use of that. But without the Head and Tail construction, I get only a single list element back, as you mentioned.
If I write only Result, without the [] then i also get only a single element back as result. Thats why i meant, I can't write it easily. I refer to the predicate.

Comment: Is a uninstantiated anonymous variable the same like _ ?
_ I learned as anonymous variable.

Comment: Technically, `_` is the only anonymous variable. I misspoke in my last comment. But other variables starting with `_`, such as `_5956`, may be an internally generated variable name. Or you can use `_X` for example if you want a named variable but don't care if it's singleton but `_X` used anywhere else in the same predicate is the same variable. Whereas `_` in multiple places is considered different.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog communicates the results of computations by *binding* variables to terms. Variables can start out *unbound*, i.e., not bound to any value, and can become bound during a computation by unification.

To some extent you already know this. After all, when you write a query like

```
?- listmulti([2,1],[3,5],Result).
```

you do not specify a value for `Result` -- it is unbound. But when you run the query, Prolog will bind `Result` to a term and tell you what it is:

```
Result = [6, 5].
```

We can visualize this by printing the value of `Result` before and after it is bound by calling `listmulti`:

```
?- write('before the query, Result is: '), write(Result), nl,
|    listmulti([2,1], [3,5], Result),
|    write('after the query, Result is: '), write(Result), nl.
before the query, Result is: _G1699
after the query, Result is: [6,5]
Result = [6, 5].
```

In the beginning, `Result` is just some unbound variable, which is shown as `_G1699` in this case. (Different variables have different numbers so you can distinguish them.) After the query is run, that same variable is now bound to the list `[6, 5]`.

This is also what the tracer was telling you, although it takes some practice to read its output:

```
 Call:listmulti([1], [5], _6268)
 ...
 Exit:listmulti([1], [5], [5])
```

This is a pair of states just before and just after executing `listmulti([1], [5], Spare)`. The current instance of `Spare` is unbound before the call and is bound to `[5]` afterwards, as `listmulti` computed the element-wise product of the lists `[1]` and `[5]`.

Now consider the following version of your predicate:

```
listmulti([],[],[]).
listmulti([H1|B1], [H2|B2], AllResults) :-
   listmulti(B1,B2, ResultsForTheTailsOfTheLists),
   Result is H1 * H2,
   AllResults = [Result | ResultsForTheTailsOfTheLists].
```

When you call this with two lists of numbers in the first two arguments, operationally this will decompose those lists into their heads and tails, and compute the element-wise product of the tails. The result of this is a list of `ResultsForTheTailsOfTheLists`. The product of the heads is computed as `Result`. And then the results for the complete lists is just the list containing `Result` followed by all of the `ResultsForTheTailsOfTheLists`. Is this clearer?

The final twist is that in Prolog you can create lists and other data structures before you know what you will put in them. You can construct a list like this:

```
?- Head = a, Tail = [b, c], List = [Head | Tail].
Head = a,
Tail = [b, c],
List = [a, b, c].
```

but you can also construct the list first and only then bind its head and tail:

```
?- List = [Head | Tail], Head = a, Tail = [b, c].
List = [a, b, c],
Head = a,
Tail = [b, c].
```

And this is what is going on in your original definition: In the head, once you know that you are looking at two lists of numbers, you know that the result will be of the form `[HeadResult | TailResults]`. Having this term in the clause head builds it right away. Only later do you compute `HeadResult` and the `TailResults` through a recursive call. Overall this gives you a complete list.